# in github actions, how to give the django process permission to create a directory?

Tags: django, github, github-actions

for every user image, i create a directory and store the image there.This works as intended on my machine in automated tests and manual use but when i push to the Github, the Github actions raise bellow error which indicates it can not create the required directory to run the tests.

**PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/src/media/profile_image'**

Comment: Have you verified that you're writing to a valid path? Please include your GHA workflow in your question highlighting the path where the files are written.